# How to Find Vertices of Specific class with Tinkerpop Frames

Tags: tinkerpop-frames, tinkerpop3

I have a FramedGraph object with Vertices of different classes, for instance Person and Location.   I would like to retrieve all vertices of the "Person" class.  Here is my current method.

```
    public List<Person> listPeople() {
      List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
      Iterator iterator =  g.getVertices().iterator();
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Vertex v = (Vertex) iterator.next();
        Person p = (Person) g.getVertex(v.getId(), Person.class);
        people.add(p);
      }
      return people;
   }
```

This feels terrifically inefficient since I am looping over all vertices then dipping back in for one at a time. I looked into using the Gremlin syntax, but I don't see how to restrict by a Frames class.  Is there a more efficient retrieval method?  Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, the Tinkerpop Frame framework acts as a wrapper class around a vertex. The vertex isn't actually stored as the interface class. As such, we need a way to identify the vertex as being of a particular `type`.

My solution, I added `@TypeField` and `@TypeValue` annotations to my Frame classes. Then I use these values to query my `FramedGraph`.

The documentation for these annotations can be found here: https://github.com/tinkerpop/frames/wiki/Typed-Graph

#### Example Code

```groovy
@TypeField("type")
@TypeValue("person")
interface Person extends VertexFrame { /* ... */ }
```

Then define the `FramedGraphFactory` by adding `TypedGraphModuleBuilder` like this.

```groovy
static final FramedGraphFactory FACTORY = new FramedGraphFactory(
    new TypedGraphModuleBuilder()
        .withClass(Person.class)
        //add any more classes that use the above annotations. 
        .build()
);
```

Then to retrieve vertices of type `Person`

```groovy
Iterable<Person> people = framedGraph.getVertices('type', 'person', Person.class);
```

I'm not sure this is the most efficient/succinct solution (I'd like to see what @stephen mallette suggests). It's not currently available, but it'd be logical to be able to do something like:

```groovy
// framedGraph.getVertices(Person.class)
```

This question looks likes it's the same as this question (looks like you were first) - [Tinkerpop Frames: Query vertices based on interface type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636308/tinkerpop-frames-query-vertices-based-on-interface-type).

Comment: This looks promising.  I'd also like to know what Stephen Mallete says, but I think you are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and thanks to Brian as well. I add some more details to your answer for future comers and should delete my question later on.

Comment: @M-T-A thanks for the edit, I missed that. I'm not sure why your change was rejected, but I've manually re-added it.