# Tinkerpop Frames: Query vertices based on interface type

Tags: tinkerpop, tinkerpop-frames

I'm using `Tinkerpop Frames` to create a set of vertices and edges. Adding a new vertex is simple but retreiving vertices based on type seems a bit difficult.

Assume I have a class `A` and `B` and I want to add a new one so:

```
framedGraph.addVertex(null, A.class);
framedGraph.addVertex(null, B.class);
```

That's straight forward. But what if I want to retrieve all vertices with type `A`?

Doing this failed, because it returned all vertices (both `A` and `B`).

```
framedGraph.query().vertices(A.class);
```

Is there any possible way to do this. I tried to check documentations and test cases with no luck. How can I retreive list of Vertices of type `A` only

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Find Vertices of Specific class with Tinkerpop Frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626160/how-to-find-vertices-of-specific-class-with-tinkerpop-frames)

Answer (score 0):

This question looks like it's a duplicate of - [How to Find Vertices of Specific class with Tinkerpop Frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626160/how-to-find-vertices-of-specific-class-with-tinkerpop-frames/29639727) (also asked today).

As far as I understand, the Tinkerpop Frame framework acts as a wrapper class around a vertex. The vertex isn't actually stored as the interface class. As such, we need a way to identify the vertex as being of a particular `type`.

My solution, I added `@TypeField` and `@TypeValue` annotations to my Frame classes. Then I use these values to query my `FramedGraph`.

The documentation for these annotations can be found here: https://github.com/tinkerpop/frames/wiki/Typed-Graph

#### Example Code

```groovy
@TypeField("type")
@TypeValue("person")
interface Person extends VertexFrame { /* ... */ }
```

Then define the `FramedGraphFactory` by adding `TypedGraphModuleBuilder` like this.

```groovy
static final FramedGraphFactory FACTORY = new FramedGraphFactory(
    new TypedGraphModuleBuilder()
        .withClass(Person.class)
        //add any more classes that use the above annotations. 
        .build()
);
```

Then to retrieve vertices of type `Person`

```groovy
Iterable<Person> people = framedGraph.getVertices('type', 'person', Person.class);
```

I'm not sure this is the most efficient/succinct solution (I'd like to see what @stephen mallette suggests). It's not currently available, but it'd be logical to be able to do something like:

```groovy
// framedGraph.getVertices(Person.class)
```

Comment: Nick, I think you meant it's a duplicate of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626160/how-to-find-vertices-of-specific-class-with-tinkerpop-frames/29639727#29639727